# Amazon S3 as secure backup without multiple invoices

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I'm storing copies of database backups on Amazon S3 using the Python Boto library. But I worry that if my web server was hacked, those backups could be deleted using the credentials I need to do the upload.

Ok, so I know you can grant permissions to another Amazon email address, so I can imagine doing that after an upload then removing the original user's write access BUT in this scenario I now end up with 2 accounts and 2 sets of invoices to give to accounts every month.

Is there a solution to this that doesn't require multiple invoices, yet keeps my backups completely independent of my web server. What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just seen that Amazon announced [Consolidated Billing](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSConsolidatedBilling/1.0/AWSConsolidatedBillingGuide.html) to solve this problem.

Are there any other/better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are really worried, there is 'MFA Delete'. (MFA == Multi Factor Authorization)

With MFA - Delete 'on' - which requires versioning, no one can delete files from S3 unless they have a physical key - fob thingy that has a constantly changing number on it that needs to be entered so you can delete the file. Kinda 'secret agent man' - like.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but thought it was total overkill. What I'm still trying to figure out, is how to upload then remove that users permission to delete or overwrite.

Comment: I believe having the upload copied out to another bucket using a manager user is the only way.